# Select all string and focus when document is ready

Tags: jquery

I want to select the input when document is ready. I mean input value must be like highlighted and when I click any button from keyboard input's value should be delete. How can i do this with jquery?

```
 <input type="text" class="myText" value="First Name"></input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the text box an ID and use the [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [select](http://api.jquery.com/select/) methods:

```
<input id="myTextBox" type="text" class="myText" value="First Name"></input>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTextBox").focus().select();
});
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4BYgm/)

Answer (score 0):

By giving input an id

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input_id").focus();
    $("#input_id").select();
});
```

should do it
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

try it out

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        $('input[type="text"]').focus().select();

        $('input[type="text"]').click(function() {
            $('input[type="text"]').val('');;
        });

    })
```